# Editing a jagged array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I wish to simulate a taskbar (of running tasks/apps). I plan to store tasks something like this:

```
(function ()
{
    var tasks = [];

    addTask = function (taskName, taskWindow)
    {
        if (!tasks[taskName]) { tasks[taskName] = []; }
        tasks[taskName].push({ taskWindow: taskWindow, taskName: taskName});
    };
    removeTask = function (taskName, taskWindow)
    {
        if (tasks[taskName])
        {
            //Somehow remove the object from the array
        }        
    };
}());
```

How should I write `removeTask()` to remove the correct element from this jagged array?

Comment: just do a for loop over tasks[taskName], find the one by taskID, use array.splice, and close this question

Comment: You might want to consider backbone.js or some other framework for MVC. You'll find such a thing very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using object to store your tasks, because it will make your ( specific to your requirement, I am not talking about Array vs Object) code cleaner and easier to maintain

```
var taskManager = (function(){
    function taskManager(tasks){
      // Do your tasks validation before passing to this.
      var this.tasks = tasks || {}; // tasks value is not private here         
    }
    // Assuming taskID would be unique value
    taskManager.prototype.addTask = function (taskName, taskID){
       if ( !this.tasks[taskID] ) {
          this.tasks[taskID] = { taskID: taskID, taskName: taskName }; 
       }
    };
    taskManager.prototype.removeTask = function (taskName, taskID){
      if (this.tasks[taskID]){
        delete this.tasks[taskID];
      }        
    };
    return taskManager;
})();
```

Usage:

```
var taskManager1 = new taskManager();
taskManager1.addTask(a,b);
taskManager1.removeTask(a);
```

Comment: The problem is I'd no longer have tasks grouped by name. Also I made a mistake in my original code showing taskID as the other piece of info I would be storing. In reality it would be a reference to the tasks dialog window, not an integer.

Comment: But I think you are right. `tasks` should be an object with properties that are arrays.

Comment: What is the point of the self-executing function you have it wrapped in?  I don't see any particular benefit it is offering.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are meant to have numeric indexes and you can use `.splice()` to remove a numeric indexed item from an array.  Non-numeric indexes aren't really in the array, they end up just being properties on the array object and they can be removed with the `delete` operator.

If you don't have numeric indexes, then you should be using an object and use a property to index each item.   When doing it that way, you can use `delete tasks[taskName]` to remove a property from the object.